# Не работает iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Сайт на wordpress, добавил в запись через админку такой код:

```html
    <iframe src="http://shop.ru/site.ru:obzor:iframe:M16:" width="700" height="820"></iframe>
```

В результате при открытии страницы вместо фрейма пустой квадрат.
А если посмотреть в инспекторе кода на содержимое фрейма, то там такое:

```
#document
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

В чём проблема?
Естественно src фрейма рабочий, т.е. если поместить этот код на другую тестовую страницу вне этого сайта, то фрейм работает.

Comment: Вы его просто в запись вставляете?

Comment: да, а что тут неправильного?

Comment: Я одного только не пойму, http://shop.ru/site.ru:obzor:iframe:M16: как он может быть рабочий? Пишет ошибку 404

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы вставить `iframe` необходимо переключиться на текст, т.е. отключить визуальный редактор:
[image: Код]

`iframe` у вас не рабочий, т.к. если перейти по ссылке, пишет ошибку 404. Ошибка 404 (Not Found, документ не найден) связана с тем, что вы неправильно ввели URL ссылки, обратите на это внимание. Результат работы вашего адреса, указанного в фрэйме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот рабочий пример, с валидной ссылкой:

```html
<iframe src="//shop.ru/" width="700" height="820"></iframe>
```

Comment: нет, у меня "Текст" был выбран, это не то

Comment: @word у меня это показало: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/ae0e3-clip-36kb.png?nocache=1   Если вставляю просто ссылку, тоже самое. Что там должно быть?

Comment: `Естественно src фрейма рабочий, т.е. если поместить этот код на другую тестовую страницу вне этого сайта, то фрейм работает.` а почему у меня рабочий? src у меня другой, это я привел тестовый src, вымышленный.